# VSCode is running two different versions of Python - one for environment and one for system

Tags: python, conda, environment, matplotlib-basemap

[image: Screen Capture of VSCode showing version of Python is different in the selected Python interpreter than what sys.version calls from the code snippet]I am trying to create geographical maps of data, and to do this I am trying to use the basemap package. As I was using Python 3.9 on Windows 10, installing basemap was nearly impossible. So I created a new environment running Python 3.6, which allowed me to install basemap with no issues. Now basemap shows up under `conda list` command, and my new environment `py36` is selectable in VSCode. Once selected, it tells me I am using Python 3.6.12. However, when I simply try to import packages:

```py
    %matplotlib inline
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    #import basemap
    import sys
    print(sys.version)
```

...basemap cannot be imported. (It is commented out in this version so that I could print the version of Python that was running in VSCode). So I commented the `import basemap` line out (all other packages imported correctly) and added two lines to print the version of Python that the code snippet was using. The result was surprising: Despite selecting an interpreter that was using 3.6.12 (see image attached, bottom of screen shot), the return for print(sys.version) was

```py
    3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

How can I get VSCode to run the version of Python that is defined explicitly in the environment, so that I can import basemap?

Thank you in advance for any help on the subject.

Brad

Comment: If you change the selected interpreter while the interactive window is open, it doesn't change the window, you need to close it and open a new one. (assuming you are running your code in the interactive window)

Comment: Thanks frab. That doesn't seem to work. I've not only restarted the interactive window several times, but I've also restarted the machine. What happens is that, now, the py36 environment is automatically chosen as the interpreter, but print(sys.version) still shows that Python 3.9 is running.

Comment: Edit: In reading other similar posts (but not finding a solution), I ran `python --version` in the terminal window of VSCode, and it showed a third version of Python running: 3.8.5 . So, to recap:  
Python Interpreter (lower left corner) : Python 3.6.12
Python from Jupyter cell print(sys.version) : Python 3.9.1
Python from VSCode terminal (python --version) : Python 3.8.5

The only one that will work with basemap is 3.6.12, so I have to conclude that it is one of the other two that is actually running.

Comment: Open the notebook as a text. It is a json file and the interpreter is specified. Check the executable or try to change it to the desired one and see what happens

Comment: Indeed, in the header information of the text file, Python 3.9.1 was specified. I changed those references to no avail. I then tried to simply start a new Jupyter notebook with the same imports and the call to print sys.version. I thought I may have some luck by starting in the proper interpreter. However, there was no basemap as the version it was now running was `3.8.5 (default, Sep 3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]` That is the version that was specified in the terminal when I asked for `python --version`. If default, does that ignore chosen interrupter?